# set value of new field depending on other field

Tags: django, model

i want setting value of new field depending on other field .to consider i want remove `like_count` after setting `like_status`'s value.
**First Try:**

my model.py:

```
class Post(Model):
       title = models.CharField( max_length=100)
       like_count =  models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

and now i want adding new field to `Post`'s model that shown me is post liked yet or not:

```
class Post(Model):
       title = models.CharField( max_length=100)
       like_count =  models.IntegerField(default=0)
       like_status = models.BooleanField(default=False if str(F('like_count')) == 0 else True)
```

after running migration ,all value of `like_status` is `True` while exist some Post's object with `like_count=0`

---

**second try:**
adding `like_status` with `False` default value:

```
class Post(Model):
       title = models.CharField( max_length=100)
       like_count =  models.IntegerField(default=0)
       like_status = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

then trying updating `like_status` field :

```
Post.objects.all().update(like_status=True if F('like_count')>0 else False)
```

the error:

```
'>' not supported between instances of 'F' and 'int'
```

and trying :

```
Post.objects.all().update(like_status=True if int(F('like_count'))>0 else False)
```

error:

```
int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'F'
```

---

i can achieve my goal by running script but i want know the way of doing this process without scripting.thank you for your time

Comment: i think you can see the first problem `str(F('like_count')) == 0` why do you compare string to an integer ?

Comment: ops, my bad. i will try again now.

Comment: when replace `int` instead `str` and makemigration ==> error :`int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'F'`

Comment: another suggestion of instead use `like_status` as a field you can  set it as a custom property function to show value based on like_count [model property](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/models/#model-methods)

Comment: i don't recall django or function name is F, where did you get it ?

Comment: you can't get other field value from the model it self it has to be in a model function

Comment: @LinhNguyen about property: i want remove `like_count` after setting value of `like_status` so model property isn't work for my goal.and about `F` you can read https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/expressions/#f-expressions

Comment: you only use that for query not for models

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Model methods](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/models/#model-methods) to set the value of like_status:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField( max_length=100)
    like_count =  models.IntegerField(default=0)

    @property
    def like_status(self):
        if self.like_count == 0:
           return False 
        else :
           return True
```

Comment: i want remove `like_count` after setting `like_status`'s value . so i can't using `property`.

Comment: why do you want to remove like_count ? that doesn't make sense to me come to designing point of view

Comment: this code are just a sample , the real model is complicated .

Comment: you shouldn't change the model fields at all because it involve migrating each time you change it and it will affect entire app